# Grouping data in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, csv

I have a file with measurement results for different settings (group) in a single csv file as shown below. I would like to plot a line in pgfplots for each group and provide an appropriate legend. Is there a way to automate the process shown below? That is, automatically recognizing which groups exist in the data and adding a line as well as a legend entry for each group.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
group, x,  y 
1.10,  1,  3.5
1.10,  2,  2.2
1.10,  3,  2.1
1.10,  4,  1.5
2.12,  1,  4
2.12,  2,  3
2.12,  3,  2
2.12,  4,  1
3.21,  1,  2
3.21,  2,  2.2
3.21,  3,  2.4
3.21,  4,  2.6
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{axis}
\addplot table [discard if not={group}{1.10}, x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addplot table [discard if not={group}{2.12}, x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addplot table [discard if not={group}{3.21}, x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\legend{1,2,3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: It already looks automated to me. What would be the extra bit?

Comment: oh, and this has nothing to do with a csv formatted file, I have removed the tag (csv=comma separated)

Comment: I hope the edit clarifies it a little bit. I have also added commas.

Comment: For others information, the `scatter/classes` method will currently not plot lines in their respective class system. Hence that answer is not viable.

Comment: Are the groups always in the first column, what should it recognize? Which style? Can you please make a proper specific question? Right now anything is possible.

Comment: @percusse I just want to generate the same picture from the same data without specifying how many groups there are and which values they have.

Comment: Is your input data sorted? If they are sorted by groups, PgfPlotsTable has something like `select equal part entry of=`.

Comment: The data is not necessarily sorted or follows a specific structure, but I wrote a python script that preprocesses the data and generates the tex code. That is faster anyway. I was just hoping to find a generic alternative without the preprocessing, but that is probably not what pgfplots is meant to do.

Comment: @koalo did you find a solution for this? I have exactly the same issue: given a group column in my data file add a separate plotted line for each unique value of the group column. Sounds like something a `\foreach` plus filtering could do but I don't know how.

Comment: @AlexTrueman As I wrote, I preprocess my data now to get this result (just learnt about pandas ;-) ). But if you find a solution that would be great anyway!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a `\foreach`?

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \foreach\g in{1.10,2.12,3.21}{
                \addplot table [discard if not={group}{\g}, x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
            }
            \legend{1,2,3}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a good first step, but you still have to specify every group explicitly.

Comment: @Koalo Good point. I guess there is a method to obtain a non-repeated list of entries that shows up in an pgfplotstable. If not, you can ask a new one!

Comment: **6 years later...** is the a way to make this work if the value used in `\ifx` is not numeric? So instead of `1.10` something like `example.com`?

Comment: @YanFoto Probably an easier way is to generate a new table using some filter syntax.  Either pgfplotstable has it or you do it yourself.  Either way, it's a good idea to ask a standalone question.

Comment: @Symbol1 cheers for the quick response. I ended up adding a new numerical column that denotes each string group. I'm reluctant to "one table per group" solution since I'm going to have non-constant number of groups (depending on my data).