# Applying multiple filters to plot data

Tags: pgfplots

I have seen people apply a filter to imported data before plotting with pgfplots, see [grouping data in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264330/grouping-data-in-pgfplots). Is there a way to extend the approach presented there to apply multiple filters? In the MWE below I made the naive modifications to the solution given there, but it seems that only the last filter is applied: the unwanted y=1 data points are plotted too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.txt}
  x y z f
  0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1
  0 1 0 2
  0 1 1 3
  1 0 0 4
  1 0 1 5
  1 1 0 6
  1 1 1 7
  \end{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{
  discard if not/.style 2 args={
  x filter/.code={
  \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
  \edef\tempb{#2}
  \ifx\tempa\tempb
  \else
    \def\pgfmathresult{nan}
  \fi
  }}
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot table[x=x, y=f,
                 discard if not={y}{0},
                 discard if not={z}{0},
                ] {foo.txt};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{$f(x)$ given $y=0$ and $z=0$.}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course. You just need to replace `.code` by `.append code` in your definition. The first "resets" the command and applies (only) the new stuff while the later - as the name suggests - appends stuff to the previous one.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
    \begin{filecontents}{foo.txt}
        x y z f
        0 0 0 0
        0 0 1 1
        0 1 0 2
        0 1 1 3
        1 0 0 4
        1 0 1 5
        1 1 0 6
        1 1 1 7
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        discard if not/.style 2 args={
            % suppress LOG messages about the filtered points
            filter discard warning=false,
            x filter/.append code={
                \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
                \edef\tempb{#2}
                \ifx\tempa\tempb
                \else
                    \def\pgfmathresult{NaN}
                \fi
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot
                table [x=x,y=f] {foo.txt};
            \addplot+ [mark=+]
                table [
                    x=x,y=f,
                    discard if not={y}{0},
                    discard if not={z}{0},
                ] {foo.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]